# OCR on PDFs using links in python

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to perform OCR on PDFs that I get from any website links without downloading the file locally.

I have performed OCR on PDF that exists on my local system using the following code :

```
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob

pdfs = glob.glob(r"file.pdf")

pdf_text = ""

for pdf_path in pdfs:
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_path, 500)

    for pageNum,imgBlob in enumerate(pages):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgBlob,lang='eng')
        pdf_text+=text
        print(text)
```

The `file.pdf` is the file in my local system.

I want to perform similar OCR for pdfs that I get using any website/Link. For example : A pdf in the link `https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/25a356ef-ad16-46f0-9778-c206b7750781.pdf`

Comment: Is it possible for you to share an example with us?

Comment: Yes sure. I shared a link there..that's an example. I want to perform OCR on PDFs from links like that without downloading the file locally.